# Update model from web controller Odoo v8

Tags: python, forms, odoo, qweb

I have this controller:

```
@route('/contrato/crear/', type='http', auth='public',website=True)
def create(self, **post_data):
    form = CuidumForm(request.httprequest.form)
    form.partner_id.choices = [
        (partner.id, partner.name)
        for partner in request.env['res.partner'].search([])
    ]
    if request.httprequest.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        request.env['account.periodical_invoicing.agreement'].create(dict([
            (field_name, field.data)
            for field_name, field in form._fields.iteritems()
        ]))
        return request.render(
            'website_create_partner.success',
            {'name': form.name.data})
    return request.render(
        'website_create_partner.contrato_new',
        {'form': form})
```

And then this form from `WTForms`:

```
class CuidumForm(Form):
    name = StringField(_('Nombre periodical'),
        [Required(_('Please enter a name for the invoicing'))])
    nombre = StringField(_('Nombre'),
        [Required(_('Please enter a name for the Partner'))])
    n_seguridad_social = StringField(_('N de Seguridad Social'))#, [
    fecha_nacimiento = DateField(_('Fecha de nacimiento'), format='%d/%m/%Y', validators=(validators.Optional(),) )
    grado_discapacidad = StringField(_('Grado de discapacidad'))
    partner_id = SelectField(_('Country'), coerce=int)
```

This logic, actually creates a new record on `account.periodical_invoicing.agreement` now, I'd like to Update records from this model instead of creating new ones, how can I achieve this?

I'm really stuck on this one.

I'll need to load this web form from a form view in backend, and attach the update to this form view.

For example I load this with a button, from x form view in backend, it loads this web form with fields to update, then save and it saves it on the specific form view I was browsing.

I'm sorry if this sounds noob, but I'm new to the Odoo v8 api, and I'm very confused at this one.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks.

**EDIT**

I'm doing it like this, but it still creates a new record:

```
@route('/contrato/editar/', type='http', auth='public',website=True)
def edit(self, **post_data):
    form = CuidumForm(request.httprequest.form)
    form.partner_id.choices = [
        (partner.id, partner.name)
        for partner in request.env['res.partner'].search([])
    ]
    if request.httprequest.method == 'GET' and form.validate():
        request.env['account.periodical_invoicing.agreement'].update(dict([
            (field_name, field.data)
            for field_name, field in form._fields.iteritems()
        ]))
        return request.render(
            'website_create_partner.success',
            {'name': form.name.data})
    return request.render(
        'website_create_partner.contrato_editar',
        {'form': form})
```

And in my xml:

```
<template id="contrato_editar" name="Edicion">
<t t-call="website.layout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <form role="form" action="/contrato/editar" method="GET">
                <t t-foreach="form" t-as="field">
                    <t t-call="website_create_partner.field_render_cuidum" />
                </t>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt8">Guardar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
</template>
```

I'm still confused, :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new url handler  **/contrato/update/**

```
 @route('/contrato/update/', type='http', auth='public',website=True)
```

Here in case of **GET** also render the **id** of model in hidden  fields

And at the time of **POST**(update ) firstly **browse** the record and then perform **write** with the post data like as below:

```
  obj = request.env['account.periodical_invoicing.agreement'].browse( post.get(id))
  obj.write(post)
```

Finally render the updated data (same as in case of **GET**)

Hope it may help in your case/

Comment: Hello @PrakashSharma , Thank You very much, I've tried like my edit in the meantime, if it's not too much to ask, could You please check my Edit to see what's wrong there? Or where I should actually browse the record on that logic? Thank You very much again.

Comment: replace the 'GET' with 'POST' like request.httprequest.method == 'POST' and instead of update  firstly  browse(by using id from post.get('id')) and then call write with the post data